# Modular Quadratic Equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I'm trying to solve that equation:

$x^2-3x-5\equiv0\pmod{343}$

I've completed the square as follows:

$x^2-3x-5 \equiv x^2+340x-5\equiv(x+170)^2-170^2-5\pmod{343}\\
(x+170)^2 \equiv 93\pmod{343}\\
y^2 \equiv 93 \pmod{343}$

But I have no idea how to move on. How can I use the fact that $343=7^3$?

Comment: Has (Hensel) lifting been done in your course already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

Start with $x^2-3x-5\equiv0\pmod7\iff0\equiv x^2-3x-5+7=(x-1)(x-2)$

If $x-1\equiv0\pmod7, x=7a+1$ where $a$ is any integer

Now $x^2-3x-5=(7a+1)^2-3(7a+1)-5=49a^2-7a-7$

which $\equiv0\pmod{7^2}\iff7|(a+1)\implies a\equiv-1\pmod7, a=7b-1$ where $b$ any integer

$\implies x=7a+1=7(7b-1)+1=49b-6$

Now $x^2-3x-5=(49b-6)^2-3(49b-6)-5\equiv49(-15b+1)\pmod{7^3}$

which will be $\equiv0\iff-15b+1\equiv0\pmod7\iff b\equiv1$

Answer (score 0):

$$y^2\equiv93\pmod{343}\implies y^2\equiv93\pmod{49}\implies y^2\equiv93\pmod{7}$$

From the last congruence we get $y\equiv\pm3\pmod 7$ or $y=7z\pm 3$. Now, plug this into the second congruence to get
$$\pm21z+9\equiv-5\pmod{49}$$
or
$$\pm3z\equiv-2\pmod 7\iff z\equiv\mp3\pmod 7$$
so $z=7u\mp 3$ and $y=7(7u\mp 3)\pm 3=49u\mp21\pm 3$. So $y=49u\pm 18$.

Finally, put this into the first congruence:
$$\pm49u+324\equiv 93\pmod{343}$$

The rest should be quite straightforward.